# Can "lend" and "borrow" refer to money?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, finance

I'm not sure how to use the following words correctly in finance.

Until now, I've used *lend* and *borrow* to represent acts that are relative to loans. Today, one of my friends told me that *lend* or *borrow* is not the correct way to speak about the money, but didn't recommend any other words to use. Can anybody point me in the right direction on this?

Moreover, I know the word *repayment* is the act of paying back money that I've borrowed, but don't know the word that represents people returning money that I've lent them.

Comment: 'Lend' and 'borrow' are the correct way to speak about money (when a loan is made). I'd be very curious what alternatives your friend could ever come up with, and why he thinks those two are not supposed to be used with money.

Comment: Yes, it's a very strange idea; the [Commercial Transaction](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/valueworthpricecost.pdf) is the most common use for _lend_ and _borrow_, and it involves -- indeed, it defines -- what _money_ is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Lend* and *borrow* are fine for very nearly all cases (there may be specialised terms for corporate finance, although even there companies borrow money from banks which lend it).

You can make a *repayment* (as you mention), and someone can make a repayment to you: you can say "He's repaying the loan I made him; I've received a repayment from him." Just as the word *loan* is used for the money which changes hands when someone lends it, *repayment* is the sum of money which moves in the opposite direction.

However, while *repay* is obvious for *make a repayment*, having looked at a number of resources I can't find a one-word synonym for *receiving a repayment*. There are words which indicate forcing the repayment of the loan: *foreclose* and *reclaim*, for example; but the simple act of receiving a sum of money someone is repaying doesn't appear to have one. *Receive* isn't specific enough<sup>1</sup>.

<sup>1</sup> The head of a Customs Office in the UK is called a Receiver, because it's his office which receives customs dues. Similarly the Metropolitan Police used to have a [Receiver](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metropolitan_Police_Receiver) who was responsible for the funds received from central and local government.

Comment: I wonder whether the original statement wasn’t related to the tendency to use *loan* as a verb, particularly when money is involved.